# Working with key/value schema and Fat Free Framework Mapper

Tags: php, mysql, fat-free-framework

I have a settings table which stores various tenant settings like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `client_settings` (
  `key` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Is there an easy way to use the mapper to things like:

```
$mapper->get('key')
```

or

```
$mapper->set('key','value')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such thing built into the mapper. You have to create a mapper for the mapper, which does that. I made a very basic example:

```
class client_settings {
    private $mapper;

    function __construct() {
        $f3 = Base::instance();

        $mapper = new \sql\mapper($f3->get('DB'), 'client_settings');
    }

    function get($key) {
        $this->mapper->load('key = ?', $key);
        return $this->mapper->key;
    }

    function set($key, $value = '') {
        $this->mapper->load('key = ?', $key);
        $this->mapper->key = $value;
        $this->mapper->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have accepted the answer, with my working code posted below

Answer (score 0):

I have accepted the answer from @sascha above because I liked the idea of an 'external' mapper within the model, but the code presented didn't work for various reasons. Here is what I used in the end, based on his suggestion:

```
class Settings {

    private $mapper;

    function exists($key){
        $this->mapper->load(array('`key` = ?', $key));
        return !$this->mapper->dry();
    }

    function get($key) {
        $this->mapper->load(array('`key` = ?', $key));
        return $this->mapper->get('value');
    }

    function set($key, $value = '') {
        $this->mapper->load(array('`key` = ?', $key));
        $this->mapper->set('key',$key);
        $this->mapper->set('value',$value);
        $this->mapper->save();
    }

    function __construct() {
        $this->mapper = new \DB\SQL\Mapper(\Base::instance()->get('DB'),'settings');
    }

}
```